# trouble setting index values to date.time pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have indexed my dataframe to the date column. Now I want to set the index to_datetime. My code follows:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import glob

​

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, sep='|', header=None, index_col=None, low_memory=False) for f in glob.glob('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/Thesis/FEC_data/itpas2_data/itpas2**.txt')))



df.columns = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', 'date', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22']                

df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date']), inplace=True)

​



df1 = df[['1', '6', '7', '10', '12', '13', '15', '16', '17']].copy() 

df1.columns = ['cmte_id', 'trans_typ', 'entity_typ', 'state', 'employer', 'occupation', 'amount', 'fec_id', 'cand_id']

Print (df1)    ​
```

But my output looks like it is appending a new date column.

```
                   cmte_id trans_typ entity_typ state employer  \
date                                                                           
1970-01-01 00:00:00.008152007  C00112250       24K        ORG    DC      NaN   
1970-01-01 00:00:00.009262007  C00119040       24K        CCM    FL      NaN   
1970-01-01 00:00:00.009262007  C00119040       24K        CCM    MD      NaN   
1970-01-01 00:00:00.00
```

My original date column is the last 8 digits in the date index. Additionally, the first few lines from the read.csv file follows (the date value in the first row is 08152007):

```
C00112250|N|Q3|G|27931381854|24K|ORG|HILLARY CLINTON FOR PRESIDENT EXP. COMM.|WASHINGTON|DC|20013|||08152007|2000|C00431569|P00003392|71006.E7975|307490|||4101720071081637544
```

Comment: It looks like your `date` values are in fact epoch times, can you try this: `df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s'), inplace=True)`

Comment: I just applied your code: Now, I'm getting this in the date column:                      1970-04-05 08:26:47

Comment: Post raw data, like I've asked on your previous questions this avoids ambiguity

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The edit has been made to show the first line of the raw data

Comment: Your date format looks like %m%d%Y but it's 7 digits and not 8 digits how did you generate these values? You can do `df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str), format='%m%d%Y'), inplace=True)`

Comment: I have downloaded this data from the FEC.gov site. It's campaign finance data. I applied your code, but am getting an
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I see your problem change your `read_csv` line to this:

```
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, sep='|', header=None, names=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', 'date', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22'], index_col=None, dtype={'date':str}) for f in glob.glob('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/Thesis/FEC_data/itpas2_data/itpas2**.txt')))
```

This sets your column names and forces the date column to be treated as a `str` dtype, before it treated it as an `int` so it removed the leading `0`, you can then convert the type:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m%d%Y), inplace=True)
```

Example:

```
In [336]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""C00112250|N|Q3|G|27931381854|24K|ORG|HILLARY CLINTON FOR PRESIDENT EXP. COMM.|WASHINGTON|DC|20013|||08152007|2000|C00431569|P00003392|71006.E7975|307490|||4101720071081637544"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='|', header=None, names=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', 'date', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22'], index_col=None, dtype={'date':str})
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 22 columns):
1       1 non-null object
2       1 non-null object
3       1 non-null object
4       1 non-null object
5       1 non-null int64
6       1 non-null object
7       1 non-null object
8       1 non-null object
9       1 non-null object
10      1 non-null object
11      1 non-null int64
12      0 non-null float64
13      0 non-null float64
date    1 non-null object
15      1 non-null int64
16      1 non-null object
17      1 non-null object
18      1 non-null object
19      1 non-null int64
20      0 non-null float64
21      0 non-null float64
22      1 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(4), int64(5), object(13)
memory usage: 184.0+ bytes

In [337]:    
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m%d%Y')
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 22 columns):
1       1 non-null object
2       1 non-null object
3       1 non-null object
4       1 non-null object
5       1 non-null int64
6       1 non-null object
7       1 non-null object
8       1 non-null object
9       1 non-null object
10      1 non-null object
11      1 non-null int64
12      0 non-null float64
13      0 non-null float64
date    1 non-null datetime64[ns]
15      1 non-null int64
16      1 non-null object
17      1 non-null object
18      1 non-null object
19      1 non-null int64
20      0 non-null float64
21      0 non-null float64
22      1 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(4), int64(5), object(12)
memory usage: 184.0+ bytes

In [338]:
df['date']

Out[338]:
0   2007-08-15
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: @ EdChum: Thanks again! I would be pretty lost with this community and its members.

Comment: For future reference, you should always try to post raw data, code, errors and desired output. Here the key thing was the raw data